# Angular: Blur input on enter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got an editable **oneline** headline like this:

```
<h1 class="headline" contenteditable="true" [textContent]="headline.name" (input)="headline.name=$event.target.textContent" (keydown.enter)="submit();false">
```

However, when I hit enter the input field keeps its focus.
How can I make it lose focus on enter?

Comment: Set the focus to something else? I believe the focus has to be somewhere at any given time.

Comment: `(keydown.enter)="$event.target.blur();submit();false"`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167) pointed out in the comments:

```
(keydown.enter)="$event.target.blur();submit();false"
```

Comment: May I know what is the 'false' do?

Comment: @luke77 shorthand for $event.preventDefault() but this should be moved into method which explicitly return false

Answer (score 8):

You can use sharp symbole to creates a template variable that references element directly:

```
<input type="text" #search (keyup.enter)="search.blur()">
```

Comment: -1 is a bit too much, I think. It will impact negatively the relevance of the answer.
Wouldn't a comment be enough ?

Comment: I'm happy to come back and reverse my vote when you improve the answer and ping me with a comment like that.

Comment: using ID solves the Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire blur event with key enter event, then simply pass `$event` in function and `$event.target.blur();` in the function.

Ex: `<div (keyup.enter)="getControl(value,$event)"></div>`
and in function, add

`getSearchControl(ctrl, event) { event.target.blur(); // your code }`